# How to rag left each specified cells in table which is fixed width in Latex?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I want to rag left the third column, except the first row which is still centered, but I can't do for a quite few times. Can somebody help me ? Thank you.

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

    \usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
    \usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

    \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

     \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{ | C{0.23\textwidth} | C{0.15\textwidth}| C{0.25\textwidth} | C{0.13\textwidth} | } 
                \hline
                Họ và tên & MSSV & Phân công nhiệm vụ & Đánh giá \\
                \hline
                Đỗ Thị Thu Ngân & 43.01.101.056  & Nghiên cứu tài liệu Chương trình phổ thông tổng thể về hoạt động trải nghiệm, xây dựng và tổ chức hoạt động 1. & 30\%  \\
                \hline
                Nguyễn Thanh Thanh & 43.01.101.056  & Xây dựng và tổ chức hoạt động 2 và 3, chuẩn bị dụng cụ dạy học cho phần thuyết trình của nhóm. & 20\%  \\
                \hline
                Nguyễn Võ Diễm Thy & 43.01.101.102  & Lên ý tưởng tổ chức các hoạt động thực hành, trải nghiệm, tổng hợp bài báo cáo, trình bày bố cục bài báo cáo. & 30\%  \\
                \hline
                Trịnh Thị Khánh Vy & 43.01.101.056  & Lên ý tưởng tổ chức các hoạt động thực hành, trải nghiệm, thiết kế bài trình chiếu. & 20\%  \\
                \hline
                & & & Tổng: 100\% \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To left align the third column, use L instead of C. If you want to right align the contents, use R instead. To nevertheless center the text in the first row, either use a multicolumn command or the makecell package.

Comment: Can you explain in detail how to use multicolumn command and makecell package ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have two examples; the first using a more traditional layout of the table; the second is your example with the layout more or less unchanged.

**Example 1 - tabulary and booktabs**

I suggest using [tabulary](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabulary) instead of defining the L, R and C column yourself. Then you may utilise the whole line width much better. Use the command `\tymin` to to avoid that first and last columns are set too narrow. I also suggest moving the per cent sign (%) to the heading of the last column instead of repeating it for each row. The second column, I have set as an ordinary `c`-column to avoid line breaks. I suggest not to centre the cell contents vertically, because it looks much better when aligned at first baseline (top).

In addition, I have used [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) to have better spacing, and removed vertical rules. I suggest that you consider setting the first column left aligned (L-column). It will look nicer.

Centring of the third heading is easy using `\multicolumn`. If `\multicolumn` spans one column only, it applies special formatting to one cell, overriding the column definition. I have used the same trick in the third column in the last row, by moving the word to the right of the cell, which reduces the width of the last column.

[image]

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

    \usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
    \usepackage{array, tabulary, booktabs}

\begin{document}

     \begin{center}
     \tymin=1.8cm
            \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{@{}CcLC@{}} 
                \toprule
                Họ và tên & MSSV & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Phân công nhiệm vụ} & Đánh giá (\%) \\
                \midrule
                Đỗ Thị Thu Ngân & 43.01.101.056  & Nghiên cứu tài liệu Chương trình phổ thông tổng thể về hoạt động trải nghiệm, xây dựng và tổ chức hoạt động 1. & 30 \\

                Nguyễn Thanh Thanh & 43.01.101.056  & Xây dựng và tổ chức hoạt động 2 và 3, chuẩn bị dụng cụ dạy học cho phần thuyết trình của nhóm. & 20 \\

                Nguyễn Võ Diễm Thy & 43.01.101.102  & Lên ý tưởng tổ chức các hoạt động thực hành, trải nghiệm, tổng hợp bài báo cáo, trình bày bố cục bài báo cáo. & 30 \\

                Trịnh Thị Khánh Vy & 43.01.101.056  & Lên ý tưởng tổ chức các hoạt động thực hành, trải nghiệm, thiết kế bài trình chiếu. & 20 \\
                \midrule
                & & \multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{Tổng:} & 100 \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabulary}
        \end{center}
\end{document}
```

**Example 2 - tabular with | and \hline**

In this example, I have only corrected the width of the first and fourth column to avoid text overrun. In addition, I have centred the third heading and left aligned rest of the column, as you ask for. Remember to add the right vertical line in the column definition when using multicolumn (`{c|`}. I suggest that you add some distance between cell content and the `\hrule` by using the command

```
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
```

The added space will be added above the text (I have not used this command in the example):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{center}
   \begin{tabular}{ | C{0.23\textwidth} | C{0.18\textwidth}| L{0.25\textwidth} | C{0.16\textwidth} | } 
         \hline
         Họ và tên & MSSV & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Phân công nhiệm vụ} & Đánh giá \\
         \hline
         Đỗ Thị Thu Ngân & 43.01.101.056  & Nghiên cứu tài liệu Chương trình phổ thông tổng thể về hoạt động trải nghiệm, xây dựng và tổ chức hoạt động 1. & 30\%  \\
         \hline
         Nguyễn Thanh Thanh & 43.01.101.056  & Xây dựng và tổ chức hoạt động 2 và 3, chuẩn bị dụng cụ dạy học cho phần thuyết trình của nhóm. & 20\%  \\
         \hline
         Nguyễn Võ Diễm Thy & 43.01.101.102  & Lên ý tưởng tổ chức các hoạt động thực hành, trải nghiệm, tổng hợp bài báo cáo, trình bày bố cục bài báo cáo. & 30\%  \\
         \hline
         Trịnh Thị Khánh Vy & 43.01.101.056  & Lên ý tưởng tổ chức các hoạt động thực hành, trải nghiệm, thiết kế bài trình chiếu. & 20\%  \\
         \hline
         & & & Tổng: 100\% \\
         \hline
   \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```